# Personalizar Pagina de erro webView android

Tags: java, android, webview

Por favor tenho uma webview em meu app android, como poso personalizar caso o user não tenha internet ?
Obrigado

Codigo do webcview atual :

```html
WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings(); 
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        ws.setSupportZoom(true); 
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl("http://google.com");
```

Código sugerido por @PauloRodrigues :

```html
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;  
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient; 
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!Functions.isDeviceOnline(context)) {
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/no-internet.html");
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
}


public class ConectActivity extends Activity { 

    public static boolean isDeviceOnline(Context pContext) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);
       
        
        WebView wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView); 
        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings(); 
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        ws.setSupportZoom(true); // *** Permite o zoom no webview - Augusto Furlan ***
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        wv.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 


    }
}
```

Comment: Adicione o código para que a galera possa te ajudar. Aproveite também e veja [ask]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você não mencionou, mas supondo que você tenha uma classe `Functions` com um método estático para verificar a conexão com a internet, assim:

```
public static boolean isDeviceOnline(Context pContext) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) pContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
}
```

E então, você vai precisar sobrescrever o método `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` do seu `WebViewClient`:

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (!Functions.isDeviceOnline(context)) {
            view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/no-internet.html");
        } else {
            view.loadUrl(url);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

E definir no seu `WebView`:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

O arquivo `no-internet.html` é o seu *HTML* personalizado para o caso de não haver conexão com a internet. Este arquivo você coloca no diretório **assets** do seu projeto.

Comment: inseri o codigo na pergunta, como posso fazer ? Pois nao entendi bem .... Obrigado

Comment: Você precisa criar uma nova classe que estende de `WebViewClient`, e esta você define no mesmo local que você fez `setWebViewClient`, como eu demonstrei na minha resposta. Você terá um caminho caso tenha conexão e caso contrário, carregar um *HTML* local informando a falta dela.

Comment: eu importo essa classe atraves do import ? como importaria ela ? Onde é melhor criar ela ?

Comment: Se criar um arquivo, você usa `import`, como qualquer outra. Ou pode ser uma classe interna.

Comment: realizei todos os imports mas ele da erro  .... Vou colocar o codigo completo como esta

Comment: Você criou a classe `CustomWebViewClient` mas na hora de definir com `setWebViewClient` você não a utilizou. [Veja aqui](http://pastebin.com/FjtLFtvR) um exemplo completo.

Comment: eu eguei o arquivo igual do exemplo porem esta dando erro aqui : if (!isDeviceOnline()) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/not-found.html");

Comment: Coloquei errado, é `view.loadUrl`, não `webView`.

Comment: resolveu, mas esta com erro no getSystemService

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30627/discussion-between-paulo-rodrigues-and-augusto-furlan).

Comment: deu certo , não foi por este código, mas deu .... XD , vou postar o código